# Rails Route Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying a basic Rails application, and my application keeps throwing me an error that says:

```
No route matches [POST] "/slides/new"
```

I can't figure out how to get this working.  Here is the form I am trying to implement:

```
<%= form_for :slide do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :picture %><br>
        <%= f.file_field :picture %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :user %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :user %><br>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>

<%end%>
```

For good measure, here is my routes document:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :slides
  resources :entries
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

I have tried following the steps of a tutorial to do something different, but somewhere in trying to apply what I learned to a different application, I must have missed something, but I can't figure out what it would be. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but you probably want

```
form_for @slide do |f|
```

instead of

```
form_for :slide do |f|
```

The former will generate a route for the instance object, while the latter tries to generate a route for a symbol (not sure what the expected behavior would be there).

When generating for an instance object, `form_for` will check to see if it's a `new_record?`.  If it is, it'll create a route for `/create`.  If it isn't, it'll go to `/update`.  Either way, `POST`ing to `/new` doesn't make a lot of sense, since `/new` is usually a `GET` request.

Comment: Haha, well that didn't take long.  I don't know if I'm happy or upset that it was something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the form_for helper can't make a correct path for :slide symbol. You can specify the path manually:

```
<%= form_for :slide, url: {controller: "slides", action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

Or use @slide instance variable (you should assign this variable in controller) instead of  :slide symbol

Comment: The other guy already got marked as the solution, but yes, the @slide vs. :slide was what tripped me up.  Thank you!